# How to extract the data in a java.util.Map object?

Tags: java, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the [Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive#override-onmessagereceived), there is this code sample:

```
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
  if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
  }
}
```

Android Studio tells me that `remoteMessage.getData()` returns a type of `java.util.Map`. The data at the sending end is in Json format, and if the data sent is `{"a":"b","c":"d"}`, `remoteMessage.getData().toString()` will produce:

```
{a=b, c=d}
```

I am very new to Java. How do I access the data returned in `getData()`, even if I know the Json structure that is used?

I tried:

```
HashMap<String, String> Data = (HashMap<String,String>)remoteMessage.getData();
```

but I got the following run-time exception:

> android.support.v4.util.Array.Map cannot be cast to java.util.HashMap.

Comment: You don't need to cast anything. You have a java.util.Map, so read the javadoc of java.util.Map, which describes all the methods available to get keys, values, entries from a map, and use them. If I give you a car, and you've learnt to drive, you can drive that car without knowing what brand the car is, what type its engine is and what kinds of brakes it has. It's a car, and it behaves as any other car.

Comment: Thanks. If I assign that data to a `java.util.Map<K,V>` object, what do I put in K and V?

Comment: `Map<String, String> map = remoteMessage.getData()` probably (depending on the type of the `Map`, but for a Json, it could be a `String, Object` or a `String, JsonObject`

Comment: Not sure why you would modify a message you get. But if you really want to, RemoteMessage.getData() returns a Map<String, String>, as its documentation shows: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData(). The documentation a Map<K, V>, shows that it has a method put(K, V): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-. So you would use `map.put("someKey", "someValue")`.

Comment: @OldGeezer the type of "a" and "b", i.e. String and String

Comment: @GregT wrong, it is always <String, String>. Values that are not strings when you send them are converted to strings before they are delivered

Comment: Start with the [`Firebase RemoteMessage`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) documentation to find the correct return type. `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: For syntax errors press alt+enter AS will give you solutions you can pick one.

Comment: @TimCastelijns You're right. I answered from a Map perspective, not a Firebase perspective. But it still applies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we look at the documentation of [`RemoteMessage.getData()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()), we see you are retrieving a `Map<String, String>`.

So you just need to use the method [`Map.get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#get(java.lang.Object)) to get, let see... the value of `"a"`.

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
String value = data.get("a"); // > "b"
```

If you don't know the JSON, you can also iterate the map using the [`Map.entrySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#entrySet()) method

Answer (score 1):

> Android Studio tells me that `remoteMessage.getData()` returns a type of `java.util.Map`.

Exactly, it returns a `Map`. It doesn't return a `HashMap`, nor should you rely on any particular implementation of a Map. There are many other implementations of Maps, e.g. `TreeMap`.

You should just use a Map like that:

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Map<String, String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
```